# Counting word frequency in a sentence

Tags: python, pandas, string, count, nlp

I have two columns - one with sentences and the other with single words.

| Sentence | word |
| --- | --- |
| "Such a day! It's a beautiful day out there" | "beautiful" |
| "Such a day! It's a beautiful day out there" | "day" |
| "I am sad by the sad weather" | "weather" |
| "I am sad by the sad weather" | "sad" |

I want to count the frequency of the "word" column in the "sentence" column
and achieve this output:

| Sentence | word | n |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "Such a day! It's a beautiful day out there" | "beautiful" | 1 |
| "Such a day! It's a beautiful day out there" | "day" | 2 |
| "I am sad by the sad weather" | "weather" | 1 |
| "I am sad by the sad weather" | "sad" | 2 |

I tried:

```
ok = []
for l in [x.split() for x in df['Sentence']]:
    for y in df['word']:
        ok.append(l.count(y))
```

However it does NOT stop running and takes A VERY long time, so is not feasible for my actual dataset as it has 50k rows.

Anyone can help to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `zip`

```
df['new'] = [x.count(y) for x, y in zip(df.Sentence,df.word)]
df
Out[419]: 
                                     Sentence       word  new
0  Such a day! It's a beautiful day out there  beautiful    1
1  Such a day! It's a beautiful day out there        day    2
2                 I am sad by the sad weather    weather    1
3                 I am sad by the sad weather        sad    2
```

Comment: Great answer, any tips on how to do the same word search however this time in the whole Sentence column - so it counts the word frequency in all of the rows of df['Sentence'].

Comment: @OnikRahman ` df.Sentence.str.count('|'.join(df.word.tolist()))`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `pandas.apply`:

```
df['n'] = df.apply(lambda r: r['Sentence'].count(r['word']), axis=1)
```

Result:

```
                                     Sentence       word  n
0  Such a day! It's a beautiful day out there  beautiful  1
1  Such a day! It's a beautiful day out there        day  2
2                 I am sad by the sad weather    weather  1
3                 I am sad by the sad weather        sad  2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can count string in a string using below code

```html
# define string
string = "This is how you count same word of your defined string to another string using python"
substring = "string"

count = string.count(substring)

# print count
print(f"The count of the word {substring} is:", count)
```

Output:
The count of the word string is: 2